# ESP8266 AT+CWLAP gives generic ERROR message with no details

Tags: esp8266

I have been having trouble all day learning how to enable "AT" commands for the ESP8266 module.  I'm using my Arduino Uno as a bridge to my ESP8266.  So my pin connections are:

```
ESP8266     |   Arduino
-----------------------
TX          |   TX
RX          |   RX
CH_PD       |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
VCC         |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
GND         |   GND
GPIO0       |   GND
```

I initially had some success with an ESP8266 Flasher that someone [shared here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3dUKfqzZnlwVGc1YnFyUjgxelE/edit) and he provides [instructions here](https://www.hobbyist.co.nz/?q=esp8266-firmware-update).  Essentially I use an esp8266_flasher.exe to load a ESP8266_BIN0.92.bin into my ESP module.  This worked so far as in when I load up my Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, I can type the command `AT` and get `OK` response, and I can type `AT+GMR` and get the firmware version number.  But typing `AT+CWLAP` after any of `AT+CWMODE=1,2,3,etc..` gave a generic `ERROR` response, with no other details.

Has anyone else had this issue and know how to resolve it?

**EDIT**

I also tried a second way to resolve my `AT` command issues as described here: [ESP8266 No response in serial monitor from official AT firmware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083897/no-response-in-serial-monitor-from-official-at-firmware)

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread ist super old but I dealt with the same question.

1. That `AT+CWLAP` returns an error without any prior connection is *desired* behaviour. The [doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/AT_Command_Set/Wi-Fi_AT_Commands.html#execute-command) states that `AT+CWLAP` "[c]onnect[s] an ESP station to a targeted AP with [the] last Wi-Fi configuration." Since there is no last Wi-Fi configuration an error is returned.
2. Moreover if you have characters like `,`, `"` or `\` in your SSID and/or password you do have to escape them (see [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/AT_Command_Set/Wi-Fi_AT_Commands.html#id6)). The documentation has an [example](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/AT_Command_Set/Wi-Fi_AT_Commands.html#id7).
3. `AT+CWMODE=1` is the correct mode if you want your esp to be a client only.

Comment: OP is asking about CWLAP (list APs) not CWJAP (Join AP)