# ESP8266 No response in serial monitor from official AT firmware

Tags: esp8266

I've been trying to get the `AT` commands to run on my ESP8266.  I failed on my first attempt using the approach described in this question I posted:

[ESP8266 AT+CWLAP gives generic ERROR message with no details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083806/esp8266-atcwlap-gives-generic-error-message-with-no-details)

So I decided to use a second approach which uses these official SDKs and Firmware:

[ESP8266 NONOS SDK V2.0.0 20160810](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/sdks/esp8266_nonos_sdk_v2.0.0_16_08_10.zip)

[ESP8266 Flash Tools](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/tools/flash_download_tools_v3.6.5_0.zip)

I connected my Arduino Uno as a bridge to my ESP8266 based on these pin connections:

```
ESP8266     |   Arduino
-----------------------
TX          |   TX
RX          |   RX
CH_PD       |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
VCC         |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
GND         |   GND
GPIO0       |   GND
```

I then set up the flash tool with these values:

[image]

Pressing `Start` in the flash tools seemed to have finished successfully.

But when I go into Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, typing `AT` or any other `AT` commands gets no response.  I tried installing Realterm, and I set the baud to 115200, matched my COM7, checked LF CR line feeds, and then sent some `AT` commands but again, I get no response.

Anyone have suggestions on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tx to Rx & Rx to Tx.
Tx send data and Rx receive them.
Tx to Tx mean they dont have any data received.

Answer (score 0):

You have connected the Tx of the ESP8266 to the Tx of the Arduino. And the Rx of the Arduino to the Rx of the ESP8266.

This is connected wrong. The Tx Line is to Transmit data and the Rx Line is to read data.

So data sent over the Tx of the ESP8266 should be send to the Rx line of the Arduino and the Tx line of the Arduino should be connected to the Rx of the ESP8266.

```
ESP8266     |   Arduino
-----------------------
TX          |   RX
RX          |   TX
CH_PD       |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
VCC         |   3.3V (separate battery that has common ground with arduino)
GND         |   GND
GPIO0       |   GND
```

The ESP will send the data over its Tx Line and the Arduino can read that over his Rx Line. And the other way around the Arduino can send his data over its Tx Line and the ESP will read that data on his Rx Line